# Top "id" is using 50-99% of CPU

Tags: cpu, top, i386, lubuntu

My i386 Lubuntu install is running with a constantly 100% CPU. Using `top` I have diagnosed "%id" as using up a lot of CPU, usually between about 50% and 99%. Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Comment: What is "id" doing. Can you [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) it ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "%id". Will edit now!

Comment: That is a surprising name for a process. Can you post a screenshot of the output of `top` (pressing `c` so that `top` shows the full command line)? Maybe you can also post the output of `ps auxww |head` and/or `pstree`.

Comment: On what basis do you think it is running with 100% cpu? As Frederik Deweerdt said, %id is "idle" (and therefore when it is 99% your cpu usage is 1%). Are you adding up the percentages and assuming that adding up to 100 means you're at 100%?

Comment: @Random832, my lxpanel resource monitor shows full CPU all the time.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out there is a problem with the **resource monitor** applet on my computer that means it shows full CPU all the time.

The fix? Use a **resource monitor** for RAM usage, and a **CPU usage monitor** for CPU usage.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you're misunderstanding `top`'s output. `%id` is the amount of time the CPU has been *idle*, that is, doing nothing.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But then why does my resource monitor on my lxpanel show full CPU all the time?

Comment: Can you copy the first ten lines of top's output and paste it here?

Comment: not quite 10 lines (too long for a comment), but here you are:
top - 11:55:58 up  1:01,  5 users,  load average: 0.41, 0.51, 0.53
Tasks: 124 total,   1 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 21.4 us,  5.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 68.7 id,  4.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    506964 total,   498164 used,     8800 free,     9148 buffers
KiB Swap:   520188 total,     9644 used,   510544 free,   110392 cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  980 root      20   0  123m  33m 5112 S  10.6  6.8   3:19.83 Xorg

Comment: What you pasted shows: 21.4% usage by user space, 5.6% by the kernel, 4.3% in waiting for IO, and the rest (68.7) idle. It also shows the first process using memory, in this case Xorg,that uses 10.6% cpu.

Comment: Turns out I have answered my own question, but thanks for the input!